# All debian main commands broken by glibc

Tags: debian, glibc, apt

Here is the thing. I'm lost.
I downgraded from Debian 10 buster (testing) to Debian 9 stretch (stable) by editing the /etc/apt/sources.list file.

I typed :

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

All worked, lsb_release -a shown me a Debian 9 stretch version.

After that I typed these commands

```
apt-get clean
apt autoremove
```

Which shown me an error with python3.5-minimal and python3-minimal
So I tried to uninstall it

```
apt-get remove --purge python3
```

There starts the big troubles
Since this moment, it seems that all the GLIBC is broken.
At each basic command I write, there is this kind of output.

```
host:~# apt
apt: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0)
host:~# wget
wget: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30)
wget: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.26' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0)
```

I can't even connect to SSH anymore. I have a rescue console which allows me to write some commands but I can't download anything.

Is there something like a cache where I could get back python/glibc ?

This is an emergency message.
Thank you for any help

Comment: That's a downgrade from testing to stable, I've read upgrades are much more tested/working/save, not at all sure about downgrades. Just an idea but a live ISO + chroot might allow installing some packages again? Or just a fresh install of stable

Comment: BTW your question is off-topic for this site. Try other sister sites. In any cases: downgrades are not supported: some dependencies ("essential packages") are implicit. You can go to `/var/cache/apt/archive` and do a `dpkg -BOGiE *.deb` several time. Ev. increase the error limit. This will upgrade again packages, and it should fix most of problems. Ev. you can just install glibc and other essential programs.

Answer (score 0):

im guesing that your computer is amd64 if thats not right please comment and say right architecture

first do `curl -o apt.deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/aptitude/aptitude_0.8.7-1_amd64.deb`

then do(if sudo is still installed) `sudo dpkg -i apt.deb`

if sudo is not installed try with: `gksudo dpkg -i apt.deb` then do `gksudo apt-get install sudo`